# Trying to choose selected date in .NET 4.0 Web Form application to label

Tags: c#, .net

I'm attempting to choose the selected date of a calendar control in order to change the text of a label with no success. All the code I find is for the System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace. There doesn't seem to be the same SelectedDate property for the Windows Form calendar control. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean [`MonthCalendar.SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.selectionstart.aspx)?

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. Thanks. Post that as an answer and I'll vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you can use

[MonthCalendar.SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.selectionstart.aspx)

> A DateTime indicating the first date in the selection range.

There is also a `SelectionRange` and `SelectionEnd`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MonthCalendar.DateSelected Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.dateselected.aspx)

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    // change the text of a label  

}
```

Comment: Sorry this wasn't what I mean. My question was ambiguous. I meant the method, or property needed not the event.